# Replace NA values as "0" using Scala in optimized way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have my input `spark-dataframe` named `df` as,

```
+---------------+----+----+----+
|Main_CustomerID|  P1|  P2|  P3|
+---------------+----+----+----+
|            101|   1|null|   2|
|            102|null|null|   3|
|            103|   1|   1|null|
+---------------+----+----+----+
```

I need to replace `null` values of `df` as `0`. I have achieved this by,

```
val columnsListSeq = df.columns.toSeq
var newDF = df
for (index <- columnsListSeq) {
newDF = newDF.na.fill(0, Seq(index))
}
```

My resultant `dataframe` is,

```
+---------------+---+---+---+
|Main_CustomerID| P1| P2| P3|
+---------------+---+---+---+
|            101|  1|  0|  2|
|            102|  0|  0|  3|
|            103|  1|  1|  0|
+---------------+---+---+---+
```

But I need to use optimized solution than this `for loop`. How can I do this?

Comment: you could just do df.na.fill(0) it will replace all the nulls to 0. you don't have to use for loops like that

Comment: Okay Ramesh. When I tried this, df.na.fill(0) I have n't assigned it to a new data frame. So there is no change in the df. By assigning to a new data frame,I can see the change.

Comment: @Ramesh I can replace `na` values as `0`. But if it is contains some values other than `na` I need to replace it as `1` . Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrameNaFunctions` come with

```
def fill(value: T, cols: Array[String]): DataFrame
```

and

```
def fill(value: T): DataFrame
```

which can fill a subset of columns (denoted by `cols`) and all columns respectively.

However there is no performance improvement here - only a more concise code.

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132398/replace-na-values-as-0-using-scala-in-optimized-way#comment89249542_51132398):

> When I tried this, df.na.fill(0) I have n't assigned it to a new data frame. So there is no change in the df. By assigning to a new data frame,I can see the change.

`DataFrames` are immutable. Your code doesn't modify existing object it just overwrites `var`. As above there is no performance improvement here.

Comment: @user10020933. This is helpful. I can replace na values as 0. But if it is contains some values other than na I need to replace it as 1 . Is there any solution to achieve this?